# Change jquery full calendar prompt input box to dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am implementing jquery full calendar in my PHP website. when i am clicking on any date of calendar it is giving me a prompt. There is a input field asking for event title. I want to change this input field and want a drop down list in place of input field. Is it possible? This is the calendar that i am using http://fullcalendar.io/

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Please fill schedule title & add fees');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    url: 'javascript:fee_add("' + title + '","' + start +'");',
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                <?php
                     if($mysql->rowCount($query) > 0)
                    {
                        $rows = $mysql->fetchArray($query);
                        foreach($rows as $row)
                        {
                            if($row['date_time'] !='0000-00-00 00:00:00')  
                            {
                                $date1 = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['date_time']);
                                $date = date('Y-m-d', $date1->getTimestamp());
                                $time = date('H:i', $date1->getTimestamp());
                                $time_hr = date('H:i:s', $date1->getTimestamp());
                            }
                ?>
                            {
                                title: '<?php echo $row["fee_title"]; ?>',
                                url: 'javascript:fee_edit(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>,"<?php echo $row["fee_title"]; ?>","<?php echo $date . " " . $time_hr; ?>");',
                                start: '<?php echo $date; ?>T<?php echo $time ?>'
                            },
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            ]
        });

    });
        </script>



</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

This is the code i am implementing and just want dropdown list in place of title

Thanx in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Hello Rahul Desai can you please tell how is it possible?

Comment: @hardeep it would be helpful if you make a fiddle of your problem

Comment: Hello @RahulDesai can you please tell how is it possible?

Comment: No @Devjosh i am using it with php

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: https://github.com/cturpin/FullCalendar-Ajax-Php-Mysql see if this can help there must be a modal popup defined somewhere on your markup which gets shown in click event of the calendar event you should make changes to that.

Comment: $sql = 'select * from ' . FEE_MASTER . ' where user_id=' . $member->getUserId();
$query = $mysql->query($sql);

Comment: I am using same code that you send me @Devjosh Check this line  var title = prompt('Event Title:'); it is giving prompt with input field where we have to enter title but i want a dropdown list in place of this input field

Comment: @hardeep code snippets are expected to be added in question rather than posting it as an answer

Comment: ok @Devjosh thanx but please solve my issue if you can

Comment: @hardeep http://jsfiddle.net/AzmJv/903/ here is a fiddle using popup to add event using dropdown (html select)

Answer (score 0):

Prompt is a built is js component. You shouldn't attempt to override it. Try using a custom dialog/modal. jQuery UI has a great dialog component that would allow you to utilize a select element or any other html you see fit.